# override 1column.phtml file in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am working on multi store magento setup. I used conditional statement for specific view in particular store in `1column.phtml` file.I override the `local.xml` file also its worked for me,but i want separate `1column.phtml` file for each store.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you can do is have different themes for each store, each theme will have just one folder inside template/page/1column.phtml, and use other functionalities using fallback mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am new in magento so can you please let me know how i can apply this mechanism.

Comment: What you can do is, lets say you have 2 stores, store1 and store2. What you do is create 1 folder namely stores inside app/design/frontend/. Inside both folders create 2 folders,  namely store1 and store2. Inside both folders, create template folder, inside which create page folder and copy 1column.phtml from base paste it here. Perform changes you want to do in 1column.phtml in these phtmls. store1 phtml will be edited from frontend/stores/store1/template/page/1column.phhtml while store2 phtml will be edited from frontend/stores/store2/template/page/1column.phhtml.

Comment: Last step is go in backend system->designs and select store/store1 theme for store1 and so on for remaining stores. refresh the cache and its done.

Comment: I made the folder as per your suggestion but it is not working.Please have a look may be i misunderstood something.

app/design/frontend/stores/store1/template/page/1column.phtml

stores = my package
store1 = theme

and i set Current Package Name = stores
Templates = store
Default = store1.

Comment: Make sure you are setting store1 as a theme to required store from backend. When you select a theme for multstore magento model, you have options to select for which store you want to change theme for. Also, check folder/file permissions which can also prevent it reflecting on frontend. Last but not the least, clear the magento cache.

Comment: I used advanced permission module to select store while configuration and clear cache and index + check proper permission for file and folder.But still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

you need to try manual action where need your store id with this code

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() == 9): ?>
```

'9' is your store ID (just for example)
it's work for me. so you can test and let me know if problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to change which template is loaded in the controller based on the store id.

```
if ($storeId == 2) {
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock($oneColumnBlock)->setTemplate($yourCustomTemplate);
}
```

Comment: What if I want separate 1column.phtml store wise. This can be applicable is 1column.phtml is to be changed for fewer specific controller action only. Having it different store wise, will be difficult using this method. Also, writing static Ids in controller is not scalable. If you have 10 stores, there wlll be 10 if else in controllers.

Comment: Sure, don't put controller code in the controller. Just don't tell me when it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by FallBack mechanism as Blastfreak suggest me.
My folder structure is:-
app/design/frontend/stores/store1/template/page/1column.phtml

stores is my package 
store1 is my theme

And i set Current Package Name = stores in admin panel.
And Edit my CMS home-page ->Click on design tab->go to Custom Design->select custom theme to store1 under store package.
Thats it.